# Is this pseudocode of binary search correct?

Tags: algorithm, search, pseudocode

```
Boolean Binary Search (first,last)
if (last > first)
  return false
else
  Set middle to (first+last)/2
  Set result to list[middle].compareTo(item)
  if (result is equal to 0)
    return true
  else
    if (result < 0)
      Binary Search (first, middle - 1)
    else
      Binary Search(middle + 1, last)
```

What does 'O' represent? If it is the item we want to search, does we need to replace 'If(result < O)' in this pseudocode with 'If(result > O)'?

Comment: You should test your code yourself (either by hand or by writing real code and test cases for it), not ask us to tell you check whether it's correct. Also, you should probably ask whomever gave you the code to explain it (I'd argue that `compareTo` is not a good function to use in pseudocode, because its very much specific to some languages and is basically just a replacement of `<`, `>` and `==`, which are much more generally understood).

Answer (score 2):

This code contains a very subtle bug: `(first + last) / 2` may lead to an overflow if the sum of `first` and `last` is larger than the max supported value.

A better alternative is to use `first + (last - first) / 2`

You can read more about this here: 
https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Answer (score 1):

The `result` from `compareTo()` will/should contain one of the following:

```
0 : equal
1 : greater than
-1: less than
```